# Display all the simulated values in a DefaultTableModel in a GUI, not only the last one

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to display all the simulated values of the Blood Pressure simulator received from a socket

```
The UserID  sent from the socket was: 1
The SystolicBP sent from the socket was: 9
The DiastolicBP sent from the socket was: 6
The UserID  sent from the socket was: 2
The SystolicBP sent from the socket was: 11
The DiastolicBP sent from the socket was: 9
The UserID  sent from the socket was: 3
The SystolicBP sent from the socket was: 18
The DiastolicBP sent from the socket was: 14
The UserID  sent from the socket was: 4
The SystolicBP sent from the socket was: 15
The DiastolicBP sent from the socket was: 12
The UserID  sent from the socket was: 5
The SystolicBP sent from the socket was: 19
The DiastolicBP sent from the socket was: 16
The UserID  sent from the socket was: 6
The SystolicBP sent from the socket was: 14
The DiastolicBP sent from the socket was: 11
The UserID  sent from the socket was: 7
The SystolicBP sent from the socket was: 19
The DiastolicBP sent from the socket was: 16
```

But trying to display it using a DefaultTableModel using the

```
private void DisplayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    model.insertRow(
        model.getRowCount(), 
        new Object[] {
            this.getBPMSUserID(), 
            this.getBPMSSystolicBP(), 
            this.getBPMSDiastolicBP()
        }
    );
```

I get only the last simulated value in the table
7   19  16

How can I display them all?

Comment: Well, you need to invokke multiple `insertRow(...)` statements. If you only get one row then that means either 1) you only add one row or 2) you create a new model each time before you insert the row. The code you posted has nothing to do with the problem. The problem is contained elsewhere in your code. Bottom line is you need to invoke the above method multiple times. Also, why is the code contained as part of an ActionEvent? If you get data from the socket then the code that reads the data from the socket should invoke a method directly to add each row of data to the TableModel.

Comment: Also, method names should NOT start with an upper case character!

Comment: Don't post code in comments. It is NOT readable.

Comment: InputStream inputStream=socket.getInputStream();
DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
         while (true) { 
            for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++){
              BPMSUserID = dataInputStream.readInt();
                BPMSSystolicBP = dataInputStream.readInt();
                BPMSDiastolicBP = dataInputStream.readInt();
     System.out.println("The UserID  sent from the socket was: " + BPMSUserID);
            .........}

Comment: I want to pass the information printed in System.Output to a GUI using Display Button and DefaultTableModel.

Comment: *"Then how i will explain?"* [Edit] the question to add new / updated information.

Comment: *I want to pass the information printed in System.Output...* - I'm not understanding your problem. Instead of using System.out.println(...) you invoke the `insertRow(...)` method of the TableModel every time you get 3 pieces of data from the socket.